# Complex foreign key constraint in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, database-design, sqlalchemy

I have two tables, `SystemVariables` and `VariableOptions`. `SystemVariables` should be self-explanatory, and `VariableOptions` contains all of the possible choices for all of the variables.

`VariableOptions` has a foreign key, `variable_id`, which states which variable it is an option for. `SystemVariables` has a foreign key, `choice_id`, which states which option is the currently selected one.

I've gotten around the circular relationship using `use_alter` on `choice_id`, and `post_update` on `SystemVariables`' `choice` relationship. However, I would like to add an extra database constraint that will ensure that `choice_id` is valid (i.e. it's referring to an option that is referring back to it).

The logic I need, assuming that `sysVar` represents a row in the `SystemVariables` table, is basically:

```
VariableOptions[sysVar.choice_id].variable_id == sysVar.id
```

But I don't know how to construct this kind of constraint using SQL, declarative, or any other method. If necessary I could just validate this at the application level, but I'd like to have it at the database level if possible. I'm using Postgres 9.1.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think you should remove the `[python]` tag and add the `[database-design]` one.

Comment: Once I get this working with SQLAlchemy, I'm going to post the code as an answer, so I'll leave the `[python]` tag for other SQLAlchemy users. I'll get rid of `[declarative]` instead.

Comment: For future readers: See [Erwin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8395021/665488) for the SQL solution, [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8408659/665488) for the same thing accomplished with SQLALchemy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can implement that **without dirty tricks**. Just **extend the foreign key** referencing the chosen option to include `variable_id` in addition to `choice_id`.

Here is a working demo. Temporary tables, so you can easily play with it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE systemvariables (
  variable_id int PRIMARY KEY
, choice_id   int
, variable    text
);
   
INSERT INTO systemvariables(variable_id, variable) VALUES
  (1, 'var1')
, (2, 'var2')
, (3, 'var3')
;

CREATE TABLE variableoptions (
  option_id   int PRIMARY KEY
, variable_id int REFERENCES systemvariables ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
, option      text
, UNIQUE (option_id, variable_id)  -- needed for the FK
);

ALTER TABLE systemvariables
  ADD CONSTRAINT systemvariables_choice_id_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (choice_id, variable_id) REFERENCES variableoptions(option_id, variable_id);

INSERT INTO variableoptions  VALUES
  (1, 'var1_op1', 1)
, (2, 'var1_op2', 1)
, (3, 'var1_op3', 1)
, (4, 'var2_op1', 2)
, (5, 'var2_op2', 2)
, (6, 'var3_op1', 3)
;
```

Choosing an associated option is allowed:

```
UPDATE systemvariables SET choice_id = 2 WHERE variable_id = 1;
UPDATE systemvariables SET choice_id = 5 WHERE variable_id = 2;
UPDATE systemvariables SET choice_id = 6 WHERE variable_id = 3;
```

But there is no getting out of line:

```
UPDATE systemvariables SET choice_id = 7 WHERE variable_id = 3;
UPDATE systemvariables SET choice_id = 4 WHERE variable_id = 1;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  insert or update on table "systemvariables" violates foreign key constraint "systemvariables_choice_id_fk"
> DETAIL: Key (choice_id,variable_id)=(4,1) is not present in table "variableoptions".
> ```

Exactly what you wanted.

### All key columns `NOT NULL`

I think I found a better solution in this later answer:

- **[How to deal with mutually dependent inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813000/how-to-deal-with-mutually-dependent-inserts/24816197#24816197)**

Addressing the [@ypercube's question in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394177/complex-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlalchemy/8395021#comment10383559_8395021), to avoid entries with unknown association make all key columns `NOT NULL`, including foreign keys.

The circular dependency would normally make that impossible. It's the classical **chicken-egg** problem: one of both has to be there first to spawn the other. But nature found a way around it, and so did Postgres: **deferrable foreign key constraints**.

```sql
CREATE TABLE systemvariables (
  variable_id int PRIMARY KEY
, variable    text
, choice_id   int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE variableoptions (
  option_id   int PRIMARY KEY
, option      text
, variable_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES systemvariables
     ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
, UNIQUE (option_id, variable_id) -- needed for the foreign key
);

ALTER TABLE systemvariables
ADD CONSTRAINT systemvariables_choice_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (choice_id, variable_id)
   REFERENCES variableoptions(option_id, variable_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED; -- no CASCADING here!
```

*New* variables and associated options have to be inserted in the same transaction:

```sql
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO systemvariables (variable_id, variable, choice_id)
VALUES
  (1, 'var1', 2)
, (2, 'var2', 5)
, (3, 'var3', 6);

INSERT INTO variableoptions (option_id, option, variable_id)
VALUES
  (1, 'var1_op1', 1)
, (2, 'var1_op2', 1)
, (3, 'var1_op3', 1)
, (4, 'var2_op1', 2)
, (5, 'var2_op2', 2)
, (6, 'var3_op1', 3);

END;
```

The `NOT NULL` constraint cannot be deferred, it is enforced immediately. But the foreign key constraint **can**, because we defined it that way. It is checked at the end of the transaction, which avoids the chicken-egg problem.

In this **edited** scenario, **both foreign keys are deferred**. You can enter variables and options in arbitrary sequence.
*You can even make it work with plain non-deferrable FK constraint if you enter related entries in both table in *one statement* using CTEs as detailed in [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24816197/939860).*

You may have noticed that the first foreign key constraint has no `CASCADE` modifier. (It wouldn't make sense to allow changes to `variableoptions.variable_id` to cascade back.

On the other hand, the second foreign key has a `CASCADE` modifier and is defined `DEFERRABLE` nonetheless. This carries some limitations. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> Referential actions other than the `NO ACTION` check cannot be deferred,
> even if the constraint is declared deferrable.

`NO ACTION` is the default.

So, referential integrity checks on `INSERT` are deferred, but the declared cascading actions on `DELETE` and `UPDATE` are not. The following is not permitted in PostgreSQL 9.0 or later because constraints are enforced after each statement:

```
UPDATE option SET var_id = 4 WHERE var_id = 5;
DELETE FROM var WHERE var_id = 5;
```

Details:

- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032272/constraint-defined-deferrable-initially-immediate-is-still-deferred)

Comment: Oh cool, that will work great! Now I just have to go look up compound foreign keys in SQLAlchemy and I'm set :) Thanks!

Comment: @Erwin: Can all ids be defined as `NOT NULL` in this scenario?

Comment: @yppercube: Excellent question. You can easily define `variableoptions.variable_id` as `NOT NULL`. Forces you to always enter variables *before* you can enter associated options. You *can* also define `systemvariables.choice_id` as `NOT NULL` but this requires additional measures. See my amended answer for that.

Comment: Nice! Deferrable constraints is a (twisted) but valid solution, indeed.

Comment: Lots of useful information here :) I've successfully implemented your SQL using the declarative method of SQLAlchemy's ORM. I'll add the code as (yet another) answer to this question in a moment.

Comment: What an answer!  I had to cross the picket line for this!  Do you think you could answer this?  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58949/circular-foreign-key-deferrable-cascade-behavior

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** The 0.7.4 release of SQLAlchemy (released the same day I started asking about this issue, 7/12/'11!), contains a new `autoincrement` value for primary keys that are also part of foreign keys, `ignore_fk`. The documentation has also been expanded to include a good example of what I was originally trying to accomplish.

All is now explained well [here](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#rows-that-point-to-themselves-mutually-dependent-rows).

If you want to see the code I came up with before the above release, check the revision history of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I really do not like circular references. There is usually a way to avoid them. Here is an approach:

```
SystemVariables 
---------------
  variable_id 
  PRIMARY KEY (variable_id)


VariableOptions 
---------------
  option_id 
  variable_id 
  PRIMARY KEY (option_id)
  UNIQUE KEY (variable_id, option_id) 
  FOREIGN KEY (variable_id) 
    REFERENCES SystemVariables(variable_id)


CurrentOptions
--------------
  variable_id 
  option_id 
  PRIMARY KEY (variable_id)
  FOREIGN KEY (variable_id, option_id)
    REFERENCES VariableOptions(variable_id, option_id)
```

Comment: The circular reference doesn't really bother me, and I'd rather have the relationship contained nicely in just two tables. Either way, the compound foreign key is the important part, so yours and Erwin's answers are both valid :)

Comment: If you are happy with having some of your columns - like the `systemvariables.choice_id` - defined as `NULL`, then the two approaches are almost the same.

Comment: What if it's easier to delete off of a child, and the information is only written through a transation thus preventing writes where some data is missing, null?  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58949/circular-foreign-key-deferrable-cascade-behavior