# In SQL, is it OK for two tables to refer to each other?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

In this system, we store products, images of products (there can be many image for a product), and a default image for a product. The database:

```
CREATE TABLE  `products` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` text NOT NULL,
  `ENABLED` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `DATEADDED` datetime NOT NULL,
  `DEFAULT_PICTURE_ID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Index_2` (`DATEADDED`),
  KEY `FK_products_1` (`DEFAULT_PICTURE_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_products_1` FOREIGN KEY (`DEFAULT_PICTURE_ID`) REFERENCES `products_pictures` (`ID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE  `products_pictures` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IMG_PATH` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_products_pictures_1` (`PRODUCT_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_products_pictures_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PRODUCT_ID`) REFERENCES `products` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

as you can see, `products_pictures.PRODUCT_ID -> products.ID` and `products.DEFAULT_PICTURE_ID -> products_pictures.ID`, so a cycle reference. Is it OK?

Comment: Why not add a column in images to mark image as default

Comment: I would ignore the circular references argument.

I can't think of an instance where you would want 2 tables to reference each other as FK. You might as well just have a single table.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

No, it's not OK. Circular references between tables are messy. See this (decade old) article: [SQL By Design: The Circular Reference](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-design-circular-reference)

Some DBMS can handle these, and with special care, but MySQL will have issues.

---

**Option 1**

As your design, to make one of the two FKs nullable. This allows you to solve the chicken-and-egg problem (which table should I first Insert into?).

There is a problem though with your code. It will allow a product to have a default picture where that picture will be referencing another product!

To disallow such an error, your FK constraint should be:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_products_1 
  FOREIGN KEY (id, default_picture_id) 
  REFERENCES products_pictures (product_id, id)
  ON DELETE RESTRICT                            --- the SET NULL options would 
  ON UPDATE RESTRICT                            --- lead to other issues
```

This will require a `UNIQUE` constraint/index in table `products_pictures` on `(product_id, id)` for the above FK to be defined and work properly.

---

**Option 2**

Another approach is to remove the `Default_Picture_ID` column form the `product` table and add an `IsDefault BIT` column in the `picture` table. The problem with this solution is how to allow only one picture per product to have that bit on and all others to have it off. In SQL-Server (and I think in Postgres) this can be done with a partial index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX is_DefaultPicture 
  ON products_pictures (Product_ID)
  WHERE IsDefault = 1 ;
```

But MySQL has no such feature.

---

**Option 3**

This approach, allows you to even have both FK columns defined as `NOT NULL` is to use deferrable constraints. This works in PostgreSQL and I think in Oracle. Check this question and the answer by @Erwin: [Complex foreign key constraint in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394177/complex-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlalchemy/8395021#8395021) (the **All key columns NOT NULL** Part).

Constraints in MySQL cannot be deferrable.

---

**Option 4**

The approach (which I find cleanest) is to remove the `Default_Picture_ID` column and add another table. No circular path in the FK constraints and all FK columns will be `NOT NULL` with this solution:

```
product_default_picture
----------------------
product_id          NOT NULL
default_picture_id  NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
FOREIGN KEY (product_id, default_picture_id)
  REFERENCES products_pictures (product_id, id)
```

This will also require a `UNIQUE` constraint/index in table `products_pictures` on `(product_id, id)` as in solution 1.

---

**To summarize, with MySQL you have two options:**

- option 1 (a nullable FK column) with the correction above to enforce integrity correctly
- option 4 (no nullable FK columns)

Comment: This is a great overview (+1), but I don't see what advantage option 4 has over option 1. With option 1, buggy application code can create invalid data by creating a product and never giving it a `default_picture_id`. With option 4, buggy application code can similarly create invalid data by creating a product and never creating a `product_default_picture` row for it. However, selecting products together with their default pictures now requires more joins, and the schema is less self-documenting. What benefit have we gained over the initial approach to offset the extra complexity?

Comment: @MarkAmery One more join is not that of a problem, is it? An advantage for the 4th solution appears when one needs to store more attributes for the default pictures. This could work in the 1st solution as well, with nullable columns, but MySQL has no way to enforce `CHECK` constraints in that case (to make sure that all such extra attributes are either NULL or NOT NULL).

Comment: And the 1st solution has some complexity issues as well. One has to be careful on how the rows are inserted (first insert a product, then insert its pictures, then update the product to point to the default picture.) The same for when one wants to change the default picture or wants to delete a product.

Comment: @MarkAmery If with the "invalid data", you mean that the options (1 and 4) do not enforce that all products have a default picture, you are 100% right, they don't. And they can't. That was not addressed in my answer. I think this can be done only in option 3, with deferrable constraints and not nullable columns. In all other options, it can't be done with DDL only.

Comment: @ypercube Yep, you've understood what I mean by 'invalid data' correctly. I realize there's no clean solution to this in MySQL. I'm not sure the first solution has any complexity issues that the fourth doesn't; you've listed 3 steps needed to create a product, but the process under the fourth solution is almost identical (only difference is that instead of updating a product row you're inserting a product_default_picture row), which I guess is my main point. +1 to your first comment, though about wanting extra NOT NULL columns with information about the relationship.

Comment: @MarkAmery Perhaps "complexity issues" is not the best description. Still, the deletes would be messy I think. I think that's why I said the 4th is *"cleanest"*, to do insert, you need 3 inserts. to do a delete, you need deletes (either in 3 tables or in 1 with cascade.) Just seems cleanest to me.

Comment: So, if I choose the 1st approach, can I expect the `ON DELETE CASCADE` rule on `FK_products_1` to work or do I have to delete the default picture explicitly before deleting a product?

Comment: @RonInbar I think that depends on the DBMS. Are we talking about MySQL?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ At the moment, I'm using an ADO.NET disconnected DataSet. I didn't realize that it may depend on the DBMS.

Comment: Anyway, if you want when you delete a product all its pictures to be deleted as well, then `FK_products_pictures_1` FK is what matters (and should be `ON DELETE CASCADE`).

Comment: The `FK_products_1` matters when you delete a picture that is the default (and my suggestion 1 is to have that with `ON DELETE RESTRICT`).

Comment: But with SQL Server you could also use suggestion 2. It's probably much cleaner.

Comment: ypercubeᵀᴹ Indeed, that's what I want; however, when I try to delete the Parent row, I get this error saying "Cannot delete this row because constraints are enforced on relation `FK_[DefaultChild]_[Parent]`, and deleting this row will strand child rows."
I'm not using SQL Server; just a DataSet which is persisted as XML.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Sorry, I now see that it happens when I try to delete the default child, not the parent, so it has nothing to do with the `On Delete Cascade` rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146302/discussion-between-ron-inbar-and-ypercube).

Comment: Regarding ADO.NET DataSets with constraints, my conclusion is that they assume the constraints are not cyclic, but they don't verify it at design time or at run time. This results in sometimes not being able to delete a cycle, eliminating option 1 and leaving only option 4.

Answer (score 4):

The only issue you're going to encounter is when you do inserts.
Which one do you insert first?

With this, you will have to do something like:

- Insert product with null default picture
- Insert picture(s) with the newly created product ID
- Update the product to set the default picture to one that you just inserted.

Again, deleting will not be fun.

Answer (score 3):

this is just suggestion but if possible create one join table between this table might be helpfull to tracking

```
product_productcat_join
------------------------
ID(PK)
ProductID(FK)- product table primary key
PictureID(FK) - category table primary key
```

Comment: The product and the picture can have rows and `product_productcat_join` don't. A buggy application could do that. Your answer, same as @ypercube answer, are not useful at all.

Answer (score 1):

In the other table you can just hold that field without the foreign key constraint.
it is useful in some cases where you want to process with the smaller table but connect to the bigger table with the result of the process.

For example if you add a product_location table which holds the country, district, city, address and longitude and latitude information. There might be a case that you want to show the product within a circle on the map.

Answer (score 0):

John what your doing isnt anything bad but using PK-FK actually helps with normalizing your data by removing redundant repeating data. Which has some fantastic advantages from

- Improved data integrity owing to the elimination of duplicate storage locations for the same data
- Reduced locking contention and improved multiple-user concurrency
- Smaller files

Answer (score -2):

that is not a cyclic ref, that is pk-fk

Comment: I meant, "A" refers to "B" and "B" refers to "A", doesnt that hurt something?

Comment: nothing is breaking here , I believe  you should take a look at E F Codd's rules and if possible take a look at RDBMS