# How to inserting data into interrelated relationship tables using SQLAlchemy (not flask_sqlalchemy or flask-merge)?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

I am new to SQLAlchemy, I am trying to build a practice project using SQLAlchemy. I have created the database containing tables with the following relationship. Now my questions are :

1. How to **INSERT** data into the tables as they are interdependent?
2. Does this form a loop in database design?
3. Is the looping database design, a bad practice? How to resolve this if its a bad practice?

   Department.manager_ssn ==> Employee.SSN
       and
   Employee.department_id ==> Department.deptid

[database relationship diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7JDr.png)

and following is the current version of code creating this exact database.

```
# Department table
class Departments(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Departments"   

    # Attricutes
    Dname= Column(String(15), nullable=False)
    Dnumber= Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Mgr_SSN= Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Employees.ssn'), nullable=False)
    employees = relationship("Employees")

# Employee table
class Employees(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Employees" 

    # Attributes
    Fname = Column(String(30), nullable=False) 
    Minit = Column(String(15), nullable=False)  
    Lname = Column(String(15), nullable=False)  
    SSN = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Bdate = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    Address = Column(String(15), nullable=False)  
    Sex = Column(String(1), default='F', nullable=False)
    Salary = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    Dno = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Departments.Dnumber'), nullable=False)
    departments = relationship("Departments")
```

**Please provide the solution in SQLAlchemy only and not in flask-sqlalchemy or flask-migrate and I am using Python 3.6.**

Comment: i think you should read this answer about loop relationship, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10458105/4995451

but if you want to keep this structure you can make relationship with `nullable=True`. so you can insert one table before another table

Comment: Thank you @faisalburhanudin, that did solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid such circular reference design altogether by

- Declaring the foreign key constraint on just one side of the relationship
- Use a boolean flag to denote if the employee is a manager

```py
class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'departments'

    department_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    employees = relationship('Employee', lazy='dynamic', back_populates='department')    


class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'

    employee_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    is_manager = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    department_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('departments.department_id'), nullable=False)

    department = relationship('Department', back_populates='employees')
```

You can find the manager of the department using

```py
department = session.query(Department).get(..)
department.employees.filter(Employee.is_manager == True).one_or_none()
```

Comment: Although this seems correct, it would add data redundancy at **is_manager** column with too many `False`. Thank you for the solution. I will let the experienced one, to determine if the answer is correct.

Comment: IMO the "redundant" column is worth it. A circular table reference is a huge pain to manage. Denormalizing data is not necessarily a bad thing, as it can help in certain query optimization, e.g. `session.query(Employee).filter(Employee.is_manager == True).all()` returns all managers.

Comment: If we use this solution, then we can make more than one manager to the same department. Two (or more) records in the **Employee table** can have `is_manager = True` while both(or all) having the **same department_id**.

Comment: You can use sqlalchemy's `validate` or ORM events to unset the previous manager when you reassign another. Triggers can be another option.