# How to correctly create tables that reference each other?

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

Table "users" depends on "companies", "positions" and "employees":

```
create table companies(id serial primary key,
"name" varchar,
"comment" varchar,
lastmodified_datetime timestampz default now());

create table positions(id serial primary key,
"name" varchar,
"comment" varchar,
lastmodified_datetime timestampz default now());

create table employees(id serial primary key,
"name" varchar,
"comment" varchar,
firstname varchar,
middlename varchar,
lastname varchar,
isoffice boolean default true,
"position" integer references positions(id),
lastmodified_datetime timestampz default now());

create table users(id serial primary key,
"name" varchar,
"comment" varchar,
"login" varchar not null,
"password" varchar not null,
isadministrator boolean,
company integer references companies(id),
employee integer references employees(id),
lastlogged_datetime timestampz default now(),
lastmodified_datetime timestampz default now());
```

Each row has a "lastmodified_datetime" column to store time, but I would also like to store info about users (add `lastmodified_user integer references users(id)` columns).

This creates a situation when in order to create basic tables I need an already existing "users" table, but in order to create "users" tables, I need basic tables. I've also read [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446641/in-sql-is-it-ok-for-two-tables-to-refer-to-each-other) that circular references lead to a bad design.

How to implement it correctly in context of PostgreSQL?
When I try to create a table that references another table that does not exist yet, PostgreSQL aborts the query which is logical. Should I create all tables first and then alter them to include these references or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem, because the `company` and `employee` columns are null-able.  So, you can insert a user who is then allowed to modify other users.

In a similar vein, you can have the `last_modified_by_user` (I think that name is more descriptive) and leave it `NULL` when records are created.  The modification would then only be for *change* to the record, rather than for the original record.

You will have a problem if you attempt to make these columns `NOT NULL`.

Comment: I guess I failed to ask the question itself. I've modified it:
"When I try to create a table that references another table that does not exist yet, PostgreSQL aborts the query which is logical. Should I create all tables first and then alter them to include these references or is there another approach?"

Comment: Yes you should.

Comment: @CorellianAle . . . You need to use `alter table` to add some of the constraints for self-referencing tables.