# Hibernate 3.6: how to make use of deferred FK constraints when inserting entities with circular reference?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping

Consider the following Hibernate 3.6 entity mapping with a circular reference in entities A and B:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Entity {

  @Id
  protected UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

  @Version
  protected Integer revision;
} 

@Entity
class A extends Entity {
  // not null in the database
  @OneToOne(optional = false)
  B b;
}

@Entity
class B extends Entity {
  // not null in the database
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  A a;
}
```

The id of the entities is generated when a new instance is created, so it is set prior to any SQL INSERT.
To determine whether an instance is transient or not an `Interceptor` is used:

```
class EntityInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

  @Override
  public boolean isTransient(Object entity) {
    return ((Entity)entity).getRevision == null;
  }
}
```

When I try to save (in a single transaction) instances of A and B (with the references set to each other) Hibernate fails with a `TransientObjectException` (object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing).

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.setB(b);
b.setA(a);

// start transaction
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(a); // a before b or vice versa doesn't matter
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(b);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
// commit
```

When I change the mapping to *cascading save* of A.b and B.a Hibernate generates the following SQL INSERT statement for A:

```
INSERT INTO A (id, revision, b) VALUES ('aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa', 0, NULL);
```

This violates the `NOT NULL` constraint on A.b and causes a `ConstraintViolationException`.
Even though the id of B is known at insert time it is not set in the SQL INSERT.
In the database (PostgreSQL 9.1) the FK constraint on A.b is defined `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`, so if A.b was set the following INSERT statements would run without any errors:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO A (id, revision, b) VALUES ('aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa', 0, 'bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb');
INSERT INTO B (id, revision, a) VALUES ('bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb', 0, 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa');
COMMIT;
```

When I drop the NOT NULL constraint on A.b in the database and keep the *cascading save* mapping the above code to save A and B works fine.
**EDIT**
The `NOT NULL` constraint cannot be deferred in PostgreSQL, only the FK constraint can be deferred.
**END EDIT**
To be honest I didn't take a look at the generated SQL statements in this case (and I cannot reproduce it right now) but I suppose it looks like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO A (id, revision, b) VALUES ('aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa', 0, NULL);
INSERT INTO B (id, revision, a) VALUES ('bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb', 0, 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa');
UPDATE A SET b = 'bbbbbbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbb-bbbbbbbbbbbb' WHERE id = 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa';
COMMIT;
```

I know that there may be a better entity design for what I am trying to do here in the first place, but I would really like to know if there is a way to keep the `NOT NULL` constraint (and if possible also the original mapping without cascading save) and make my original code work.
Is there a way to *tell* Hibernate to just insert A with A.b = B.id even though B is transient at insert time of A?
Generally, I couldn't find any documentation concerning Hibernate and deferred FK constraints, so any pointers on that appreciated.

Comment: Sounds *a lot* like [this related case of the chicken-egg-problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394177/complex-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlalchemy/8395021#8395021). The second part of that answer may be of use here.

Comment: Also, the PostgreSQL documentation of the behaviour of constraints that are  defined `DEFERRABLE` is lacking currently, as we found out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10032272/939860).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: (as always) a very good answer to the chicken-egg problem! I am certainly not struggling with the database part of my problem, but I haven't thought of the *back-referencing* foreign key idiom yet. Really nice, it will definitely be there when my As and Bs go live ;) I don't know SQLAlchemy, maybe I need the equivalent of "I've gotten around the circular relationship using use_alter on choice_id, and post_update on SystemVariables' choice relationship" for the Hibernate part of my problem. Maybe an SQLAlchemy expert can tell me if this also covers my not-null issue...

Comment: Sadly, I am neither a Hiberante nor an SA expert. You'll need someone else to lend a hand.

Comment: I am having a very similar issue with this on Oracle 11gR2. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610914/session-flush-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is classical [bidirectional relationship](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-121). both side has reference to each other. 
If you have bidirectonal one side need to be marked as the stronger side this is done by ussing [mappedBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-please-explain-mappedby-in-hibernate)  or inverse to mark the wick side. In addtional you have FK constraints , so need to define that not-null is true in order that hibernate will insert with the FK.

look on this for [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108224/can-someone-please-explain-mappedby-in-hibernate).