# Referential cycle: ON DELETE CASCADE?

Tags: postgresql, entity-relationship, referential-integrity

[image]

If "**predmet**" is a FK to "**predmeti**", and "**nositelj**" is a FK to "**nastavnici**",

what will happen if I specify *ON DELETE CASCADE* to both foreign keys and delete one of the entities? Would it produce an error?

Edit: I'm using the latest version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: This is a bad design, it is not in a so-called normal form.

Comment: If you use and refer to an image, it might help if it were readable

Comment: `What will happen if I specify ON DELETE CASCADE to both foreign keys and delete one of the entities?` I don't know... what *will* happen? `Would it produce an error?` I don't know... does it?  What have you tried?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394177/complex-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read manual for your RDBMS (you have not specified it). Typically circular cascade forbidden - you will get an error on create.

UPDATED: try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/24df4/2/0 It seems it is not forbidden - remove recursively.

Someone very kind minused me, because i have fixed the tags and it makes my post incorrect)

Comment: I'm using the latest PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Tool 9.2.2? It's the latest *now*, but what about people reading this lateR?