# Main item of 1:N relationship

Tags: database-design

I have a `Product` with many `Images`. The `Product` has one **main** `Image`.

I'm storing this main `Image` in a `main_image_id` column in the `Products` table.

Everything is working but I am not sure about this design.

Comment: Which DBMS? See my answer on a similar question for MySQL: **[In SQL, is it OK for two tables to refer to each other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446641/in-sql-is-it-ok-for-two-tables-to-refer-to-each-other/10458105#10458105)** (and there are links for other DBMS there)

Comment: Postgres. I'll try the ypercube's fourth approach. A classic third table.

Comment: Keep also in mind, **[Erwin's answer here: Complex foreign key constraint in SQLAlchemy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394177/complex-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlalchemy/8395021#8395021)** This is how it can be done in Postgres, with two tables only and deferrable constaints.

Comment: I assume that you find your answer in here:  [Would you store binary data in database or in file system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662488/would-you-store-binary-data-in-database-or-in-file-system)

Comment: @Borys - Sorry for the delay. I'm not receiving the email notifications from Stack Overflow. I'm storing just the path for the image, not the binary.