# ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "abteilung"

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "abteilung"
> ```

For this schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Person (
    svnr VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY,
    anschrift VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE Mitarbeiter (
    svnr VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Person(svnr),
    beschaeftigt_seit DATE NOT NULL,
    gehalt NUMERIC(5,2),
    CHECK(gehalt > 0),
    abteilung INTEGER NOT NULL,
    krankenhaus INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Krankenhaus (
    kid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('seq_krankenhaus'),
    anschrift VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    geleitet_von VARCHAR(40) REFERENCES Mitarbeiter(svnr) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);

CREATE TABLE Abteilung (
    abid INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('seq_abteilung'),
    name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    anschrift VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    koordiniert VARCHAR(40) REFERENCES Mitarbeiter(svnr) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    krankenhaus INTEGER REFERENCES Krankenhaus(kid),
    PRIMARY KEY (abid, krankenhaus)
);

ALTER TABLE Mitarbeiter ADD CONSTRAINT fk_abteilung FOREIGN KEY (abteilung, krankenhaus) REFERENCES Abteilung(abid, krankenhaus) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;

COMMIT;
```

What I am doing wrong?

After adding a column `krankenhaus` to the table `mitarbeiter` and changing the `alter table` command but I still get the same error ...

Comment: The error message contradicts your code after you applied @a_horse's advice. It should work. You did pick the inferior option, though. You'd better remove the redundant `mitarbeiter.krankenhaus` and go with just `abid` for PK and FK.

Answer (score 3):

The primary key of the table `Abteilung` is `(abid, krankenhaus)`. As a foreign references references exactly one row, you also need to use **both** columns in the foreign key constraint definition.

But as you don't have a column `krankenhaus` in your table `Mitarbeiter` you can't reference `Abteilung`.

You either need to reduce the primary key of `Abteilung`to `(abid)` (which would be possible as it is a generated, artificial key anyway) or add a column `Krankenhaus` to your `Mitarbeiter` table.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks! But now I changed it as you say (see code) but I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
   svnr text PRIMARY KEY
 , anschrift text NOT NULL
 , name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE mitarbeiter (
   svnr text PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES person
 , beschaeftigt_seit date NOT NULL
 , gehalt numeric(5,2)
 , abid int NOT NULL
 , CHECK(gehalt > 0)
);

CREATE TABLE krankenhaus (
   kid serial PRIMARY KEY
 , anschrift text NOT NULL
 , name text NOT NULL
 , geleitet_von text REFERENCES mitarbeiter(svnr) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);

CREATE TABLE abteilung (
   abid serial PRIMARY KEY
 , kid INTEGER REFERENCES krankenhaus(kid)
 , koordiniert text REFERENCES mitarbeiter(svnr) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
 , name text NOT NULL
 , anschrift text NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE mitarbeiter
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_abteilung FOREIGN KEY (abid)
   REFERENCES abteilung(abid) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Use a `serial` column for surrogate PKs:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

Don't use `varchar(n)` with arbitrary limitations for string length, unless you really *need* to enforce a maximum length and its not going to change. See:

- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)

Go with just `abid` as primary key for `abteilung`. There *would* be a related application for a redundant column included in a FK constraint, but that's not what your model does right now:

- [Complex foreign key constraint in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394177/complex-foreign-key-constraint-in-sqlalchemy/8395021#8395021)

No need to use an explicit transaction (*`BEGIN ... COMMIT`*) for part of the code.

The real difficulty with these **circular references** is entering and changing data. You probably made your FK constraints `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` - which is going to make some queries considerably *slower*.
You *could* go with just plain default `IMMEDIATE` FK constraints, if you wrap INSERT / UPDATE on related rows into **data-modifying CTEs**. See:

- [How to deal with mutually dependent inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813000/how-to-deal-with-mutually-dependent-inserts/24816197#24816197)

Comment: thanks! But i need the column krankenhaus in abteilung and mitarbeiter because abteilung is a weaky entity of krankenhaus

Comment: @prodi22: What's a `weaky entity`? Either way, `abteilung.kid` should be all you need.